# React Native, Push Notifications and Background Tasks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, background-process

So I have been using RN for 5 months now and recently found out that RN doesn't have a real way of handling background tasks because as soon as the app is moved to background, js bridge is shut.

For `Geolocation` based app, this is fine because we can just re-fetch a fresh data every time app is brought back to foreground by using `AppState` listener as the event trigger.
So it's not a problem for my current project.

But just for future reference, if this is really not possible yet for RN, how does `push notification` work for apps build with RN then?
Specifically, if there's a timer based `local push notification`?

I noticed that even in the RN documentation itself the RN team have to write their push notification API on native first then link it to js. This makes projects built on expo's assumptions of pure JS coding a bit silly. I mean, for a standard business level app, of course we'll always need a small degree of native. Even if we are only using someone else's library we'll still need to use `react-native link`.

Anyhow, so I guess one way to work around issues like this is to write any background tasks on native and link the modules to RN using their `Native Modules` functionality. Another is to wait until someone more experienced in Native bumps into the same problem as you and build the lib that you can leech off of (this is what I have been doing basically)

Considering my only uni-level experience with native, this seems a tad daunting if I have to ever write Native on my own lol. Is there any other (hopefully easier) solutions that I have missed to mention here?

I'm pretty new to these stuff, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: Are you using Expo?

Comment: @iuliu.net My first project was, then I bumped into problems when RN's [backhandler problem](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15497) arose, then another when I need to use libraries that uses `react-native link`, using expo is much nicer for rapid development but it made me rely on expo's own API solely to interact with native functionalities, which caused a hiccup on my project when one of their updates caused the API to break. But that's beside the point, my question is more towards how would you go about it if this was a normal RN project but I'm not familiar with Native.